# Why do I get 'pop index out of range' error in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing, spyder

I have a problem with `L.pop(i)` function. Here is my code:

```
L = []  

for i in range(3):
    value = int(input('Enter value ' + str( i+1)+ ': '))  

    L.append(value)

print(L)

limit = int(input('Enter a limit: '))
for i in L:
    if i > limit:
        print('Index of first element over',limit,':',i)
        L.pop(i)  
        break
    
print(L)
```

It works until that part: `L.pop(i)`.
It gives

```
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

So what is the problem with `L.pop(i)`?

Comment: Try to print `i` and `len(L)` before the line `L.pop(i) ` - that should clarify it ;)

Comment: I think you are confusing `pop` (remove at index) and `remove` (remove element)

Comment: @tobias_k don't you incur in the same problem also with `remove`?

Comment: @Gsk Depends on what problem you mean. There is actually no "removing in a loop" problem here, as OP breaks after removing the element. It is unclear, however, what OP actually wants to achieve, e.g. remove the first element greater `limit`, or all, and whether limit should be compared to the element itself or its index.

Comment: @tobias_k yep, my bad. Went with assumptions (`.pop()` and `pop index out of range` are a classic!) before reading

Comment: @tobias_k - Many thanks for clarifying the difference.  (Have deleted the comment).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing `pop` (remove element at index) and `remove` (remove the element itself). With `for i in L:` you iterate the elements, but then in your `print` and `L.pop(i)` you treat them as the index.

Assuming you want to print the *index* of the first *element* that's greater than `limit`, and then remove that element, you can try this:

```
for i in range(len(L)):
    if L[i] > limit:
        print('Index of first element over',limit,':',i)
        L.pop(i)  
        break
```

Or this:

```
for i, e in enumerate(L)::
    if e > limit:
        print('Index of first element over',limit,':',i)
        L.pop(i)  # or L.remove(e), but pop might be a bit faster
        break
```

Note: Removing elements from a list, whether by `remove` or `pop`, while iterating the same list is generally a bit problematic. In this case, it is okay since you `break` from the loop right after removing the element, but keep this in mind in case you want to extend this to e.g. removing *all* elements that are greater than `limit`.